# React.js Problem with setState and useCallback using Dropzone component

Tags: reactjs

I know what is wrong but don't know how to correct this. How can I pass updated object to handler instead of inside onDrop function? I've looked for solution but I'm using useCallback function and I got error on every solution.

```
function PortfolioDropzone(params) {
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
  const onDrop = useCallback((newFiles) => {
    if (newFiles?.length) {
      setFileList((previousFileList) => [
        ...previousFileList,
        ...newFiles.map((file) =>
          Object.assign(file, { preview: URL.createObjectURL(file) })
        ),
      ]);
      params.uploadHandler(fileList); // This is not working because of async of setState
    }
  }, []);
   
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: { "image/*": [] },
    maxSize: 1024 * 10000,
  });

  return (
    <div className="mt-4 mb-4 border rounded p-3">
      <div {...getRootProps({ className: params.className })}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {isDragActive ? (
          <p className="m-0">Drop file ...</p>
        ) : (
          <p className="m-0">
            Drop file or click to choose file ...
          </p>
        )}
      </div>
      // some code for displaying loaded files and deleting them
    </div>
  );
}

export default PortfolioDropzone;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because you are trying to pass the fileList state to params.uploadHandler(fileList) immediately after updating it within the onDrop callback. The problem is that the setFileList function is asynchronous, so the fileList may not be updated by the time you try to pass it to uploadHandler. To solve this issue, you can either use the updated fileList directly within the onDrop callback or use the useEffect hook to call params.uploadHandler after the state has been updated. I'll provide an example of using the useEffect approach

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';

function PortfolioDropzone(params) {
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
  const onDrop = useCallback((newFiles) => {
    if (newFiles?.length) {
      const updatedFileList = [
        ...fileList,
        ...newFiles.map((file) =>
          Object.assign(file, { preview: URL.createObjectURL(file) })
        ),
      ];
      setFileList(updatedFileList);
    }
  }, [fileList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // This will be called whenever fileList changes
    params.uploadHandler(fileList);
  }, [fileList, params.uploadHandler]);

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: { "image/*": [] },
    maxSize: 1024 * 10000,
  });

  return (
    <div className="mt-4 mb-4 border rounded p-3">
      <div {...getRootProps({ className: params.className })}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {isDragActive ? (
          <p className="m-0">Drop file ...</p>
        ) : (
          <p className="m-0">
            Drop file or click to choose file ...
          </p>
        )}
      </div>
      {/* some code for displaying loaded files and deleting them */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default PortfolioDropzone;
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it works but same as answer above it generates infinity loop of warnings :(

Comment: The infinite loop of warnings is likely caused by the useEffect that depends on fileList and params.uploadHandler. To avoid this, you can move the params.uploadHandler(fileList) call to a separate useEffect with params.uploadHandler as the only dependency, ensuring it doesn't trigger when fileList changes.

Comment: can you explain this more? Some example? How can I use this object and function but avoid to use them?

Comment: @ŁukaszStrzelecki No surprise here - Unfortunately *both* of these answers appear to have come from ChatGPT (or similar LLM).  Even the comment reply was a straight response of pasting your comment into ChatGPT :-/